# Is there a right to allow suggestions but permit edits in google documents?

Tags: google-docs, sharing, permissions

When I share a document with others, I have three right to assign to them.

- Can edit
- Can comment
- Can view

I'm guessing `Can edit` is the right needed to make suggestions? But is there an option to enable suggestions and permit normal editing?

In the toolbar I'm able to switch between

- **Editing** Edit document directly
- **Suggesting** Edits become suggestions
- **Viewing** Read or print final document

Together with comments we have 4 modes, which seem not sufficiently covered by rights available.

Comment: @pnuts Edited for clarification.

Comment: The question as it's could lead to confusion. There is no "Commenting" mode.

Answer (score 2):

Both Edit and Comment permissions allow users to suggest changes.

**References**
[Suggest edits in a document - Google Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6033474?hl=en)